# Apache Tomcat webapps have to use a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, tomcat

I've installed Apache Tomcat and want to use a proxy for my webapps. Some apps request data from the internet, they don't have an own/internal possibility to use a proxy.

I added the following lines at the beginning of my `startup.sh`:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=foo.bar" 
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128"
```

But these settings don't seem to work.

Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34

JVM Version: 1.6.0_24-b24

Ubuntu 10.04.4

Answer (score 0):

please check if those catalina opts are loaded and where.
It's safer to use java_opts , or create an environment variables JAVA_OPTS with that value "-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 ".
Also make sure you know what JRE is used. Sometimes tomcat loads one of his own.
I used it in both ways and it worked. You can also setup the proxy dynamically at runtime, but that is nasty.

Cheers, Nicu